# Makefile stopped without any messages

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw

i try to compile some .cpp files. Use this makefile code

```
.PHONY: all

define CompileModule
$(2): $(1)
    $(call __verify_path,$(TMP_DIR))
    @echo Compile $(1) to $(2)
    $(CC) -c -o $(2) $(1)
endef

$(foreach module,$(ALL_CPP), $(eval $(call CompileModule, $(module), $(addprefix $(TMP_DIR)\, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(module))))))))

all: | setup $(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME) clean

setup:
    @echo Setup...
    $(call __verify_path,$(BIN_DIR))
    $(call __verify_path,$(TMP_DIR))
    $(call __verify_path,$(LIB_DIR))
    @echo Setup finished...

clean: 
    @echo Clean...
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.o))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.res))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.cof))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.c))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.h))
    $(call __delete_path,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)))
    @echo Clean finished...

$(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME): $(ALL_OBJ) $(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ)
    @echo Link objects... >&2
    $(call __verify_path,$(LIB_DIR))
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(call __trans,$(L_ATLANTIS)/LIB/crtexe.o) --allow-multiple-definition $(LINK_OPTION) --start-group $(LIB_MODULE_PARAM) --end-group
    $(__Strip_DebugInfo__)

$(RPC_T_MODULE) : $(RPC_T_IDL_MODULES)
    @echo Run MIDL... >&2
    $(MIDL) $(MIDL_OPT) $^

$(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ): $(RPC_T_MODULE)
    @echo Compile IDL module... >&2
    $(CC) -c -x c++ -fpermissive -o $@ $^
```

It's worked, but compile only first file from list.

Ok, i try to use code from this site (with some changes, of course) :

```
MakeTarget=$(addprefix $(TMP_DIR)\, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir ${1}))))
obj.cpp=
define obj
$(call MakeTarget, ${1}) : ${1}
obj$(suffix ${1}) += $(call MakeTarget, ${1})
$(info ${1} to $(call MakeTarget, ${1}))
endef

define SOURCES
$(foreach src,${1},$(eval $(call obj,${src})))
$(info Foreach finished...)
endef

$(eval $(call SOURCES, $(ALL_CPP)))

all : $(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME) clean

clean: 
    $(info Clean...)
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.o))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.res))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.cof))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.c))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.h))
    $(call __delete_path,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)))
    $(info Clean finished...)

${obj.cpp} : % :
    $(info ${obj.cpp})
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^

$(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME): ${obj.cpp} $(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ)
    $(info  Link objects... )
    $(call __verify_path,$(LIB_DIR))
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(call __trans,$(L_ATLANTIS)/LIB/crtexe.o) --allow-multiple-definition $(LINK_OPTION) --start-group $(LIB_MODULE_PARAM) --end-group
    $(__Strip_DebugInfo__)

$(RPC_T_MODULE) : $(RPC_T_IDL_MODULES)
    $(info  Run MIDL... )
    $(MIDL) $(MIDL_OPT) $^

$(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ): $(RPC_T_MODULE)
    $(info  Compile IDL module... )
    $(CC) -c -x c++ -fpermissive -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all
```

Same result.

In output, i see list of files with target objects (right), "Foreach complete", list of targets from ${obj.cpp} (again, right), G++ string for compilation of first module (again, right) - and nothing more. In target directory i found first object file.

Look like Make immediately stopped without any messages after compilation of first file.

What wrong?

Comment: On a first view it looks like that you run internal make subroutines for each of your files which is not the way a makefile typically will work. "Normally" a makefile contain rules and prerequisits and it simply runs the recepies of each of the rule sets. The internal functions "$(call... ) or normally used to generate something generic from some parameters but not part of any concrete objects/sources/targets.

Comment: What *operating system*, what *compiler* ? Please show some [mre] in your question. Without a lot more details, your question is not clear.

Comment: Show us a C++ code which exhibit your issues. We cannot guess it.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have given us incomplete information, so I must guess about some points.

Make must decide which rule(s) to execute; if you specify no target, Make will run the default rule, which is the first rule in the makefile (unless you specify otherwise). In your first example, I see no rule for `all`, but your `foreach` creates several rules, so Make runs the first of them, which is the rule to build the first object file in the list.

To solve this, write a rule for `all`, and give it the list of object files as a prerequisite.

Your second example is very complicated -- and incomplete -- but there is a very serious problem here:

```
${obj.cpp} : % :
    $(info ${obj.cpp})
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^
```

You may have intended this to be a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), but the prerequisite list is empty; there is nothing to the right of the second colon. So the `$^` expands to nothing, and the compiler command will fail.

More fundamentally, you have neglected a basic rule of engineering: start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. If you build a large new machine, using a strange new technology, all in one step, it will surely fail.

**EDIT:**
In your second example it looks as if you have a problem similar to the one in the first. You create several rules using templates, but you do not specify a target, so the first of these rules becomes the default rule. Make never runs the `all` rule.

To solve this, put the `all` rule above the loop that generates the `obj` rules.

Comment: I get code for second example from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942565/makefile-to-compile-lists-of-source-files

Comment: I change my post with more information about first example. Situation similar: first file compiled then all stopped.

Comment: @СергейИванов: My answer remains unchanged. If you do not specify a target (by e.g. `make all`) then Make will run the default target, which is (usually) the target of the first rule. The first rule in your first example is one of the rules generated by `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for help. This code worked propertly:

```
.PHONY: all

all: | setup $(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME) clean

ALL_OBJ=
define CompileModule
ALL_OBJ+= $(2)
$(2): $(1)
    $(call __verify_path,$(TMP_DIR))
    @echo Compile $(1) to $(2)
    $(CC) -c -o $(2) $(1)

endef

$(foreach module,$(ALL_CPP), $(eval $(call CompileModule, $(module), $(addprefix $(TMP_DIR)\, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(module))))))))

setup:
    @echo Setup...
    $(call __verify_path,$(BIN_DIR))
    $(call __verify_path,$(TMP_DIR))
    $(call __verify_path,$(LIB_DIR))
    @echo Setup finished...

clean: 
    @echo Clean...
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.o))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.res))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.cof))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.c))
    $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.h))
    $(call __delete_path,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)))
    @echo Clean finished...

$(ALL_OBJ):

$(OUTPUT_FULL_NAME): $(ALL_OBJ) $(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ)
    @echo Link objects... >&2
    $(call __verify_path,$(LIB_DIR))
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(call __trans,$(L_ATLANTIS)/LIB/crtexe.o) --allow-multiple-definition $(LINK_OPTION) --start-group $(LIB_MODULE_PARAM) --end-group
    $(__Strip_DebugInfo__)

$(RPC_T_MODULE) : $(RPC_T_IDL_MODULES)
    @echo Run MIDL... >&2
    $(MIDL) $(MIDL_OPT) $^

$(RPC_T_MODULE_OBJ): $(RPC_T_MODULE)
    @echo Compile IDL module... >&2
    $(CC) -c -x c++ -fpermissive -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

**A good open source tool to debug `Makefile`-s** (those written for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) **is [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)** (you'll run it as `remake -x`)

You could compile both GNU `make` and `remake` from their open source code then run `remake -x` to understand what and why `make` is doing.

Also,  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) has a lot of builtin rules. Run `make -p` to print them, then improve your `Makefile` to take advantage of them. For example, you should prefer `$(COMPILE.c)` to `$(CC)`

If you use some recent variant of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you want to enable compile warnings by passing at least `-Wall -Wextra` when invoking `gcc` or `g++`. If you debug with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), you want also to pass `-g`.

At last, recent  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers have *lots* of interesting options. So read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). If your C++ compiler is [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) or [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/), take time to read its documentation.

If on Linux, you probably use the linker inside [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) (or perhaps [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker))), and that linker, indirectly invoked by `gcc` or `g++` in your `Makefile`, has many interesting options.

If you program for Linux, read of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

In some cases, you might consider alternative open source [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools, such as [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), and you might (for large or legacy projects) consider combining them (e.g. run `ninja` from inside your `Makefile`).

In some applications, you might want to *generate* some C++ code with tools like [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [SWIG](http://swig.org/).

Notice that a variant of  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is scriptable with [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or extensible with [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)). And that [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and [GNU automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) can generate (partly) your `Makefile`

Certainly **look inside *existing* open source projects** on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) **for inspiration**.

---

You code has

> ```
> $(call __delete_file,$(call __trans,$(TMP_DIR)/*.o))
> ```

but why don't you use `$(RM)` as most open source project do?